# Hadoop is asking for the input path to be on localhost 9000

Tags: java, hadoop

I am trying to run the Tom Whites' Chapter 2 example

When I run the command:

```
hadoop MaxTemperature input/ncdc/sample.txt output
```

The error I am getting is this:

```
11/12/31 18:08:28 INFO mapred.JobClient: Cleaning up the staging area hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp/hadoop-mymac/mapred/staging/mymac/.staging/job_201112311807_0001
11/12/31 18:08:28 ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:mymac (auth:SIMPLE) cause:org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://localhost:9000/user/mymac/input/ncdc/sample.txt
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://localhost:9000/user/mymac/input/ncdc/sample.txt
```

What is it that I have set wrong?

I haven't touched his source code, it can be found in here:

https://github.com/tomwhite/hadoop-book/tree/3e/ch02

Comment: Can you post your `core-site.xml`, `mapred-site.xml` and `hdfs-site.xml` files? By default, they should be in `hadoop-X.Y.Z/conf`.

Comment: @PhilippeSignoret : Sure,  I posted them as a gist on Github, here: https://gist.github.com/babakinks/5281541

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `core-site.xml` and `hdfs-site.xml` files are configured to use `localhost:9000`. If this isn't what you expect (which is what I get from you post's title), what *did* you expect?

What version of Hadoop are we talking about? How did you install your Hadoop distribution? From your other question and the config files, I'm guessing you used CHD4. If you look over [the instructions from Cloudera](https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/CDH4DOC/Installing+CDH4+on+a+Single+Linux+Node+in+Pseudo-distributed+Mode#InstallingCDH4onaSingleLinuxNodeinPseudo-distributedMode-InstallingCDH4withMRv1onaSingleLinuxNodeinPseudodistributedmode), can you see if you missed anything?

Before starting Hadoop, did you format HDFS?

```
$ hadoop namenode -format
```

Then, after starting Hadoop, do you get anything other than INFO messages?

Did you copy the input data into HDFS?

```
$ hadoop dfs -put /tmp/my/input/data input
```

Finally, what do you get from simple HDFS commands such as:

```
$ hadoop dfs -ls /
```

UPDATE: Run Word Count

1. Get HDFS up and running. Running `hadoop dfs -ls /` should work.
2. Copy a folder with text file(s) into HDFS: `hadoop dfs -put text_files input_folder`
3. Run `hadoop dfs -ls .` to see if your files got copied correctly.
4. Find the `hadoop-examples-X.Y.Z.jar` file on your system.
5. Navigate to whatever directory it's in, and run:

   `$ hadoop jar hadoop-examples-*.jar WordCount input_folder output_folder`.
6. You should see the progress of the MapReduce application.
7. When its finished, view the output with `hadoop dfs -cat output_folder/*`.

Comment: as for "hadoop dfs -ls /" : I get the error of conncetion refused from localhost/127.0.0.1 tp localhost:9000

Comment: no I didn't format the node? I should have done that too?  No I didn't copy the input data into HDFS either...we should do that too?

Comment: Give it a try and let us know if it works. Appendix A can give you some more insight into the configuration, but the above command should work for formatting. I would recommend you start with one of the included Hadoop examples. I'll edit with an example.

Answer (score 1):

Forgot to set `JAVA_HOME` in `etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh` may also cause this error